# R: How to add custom character inside string depends on the group?

Tags: r, tidyverse, plyr

How to add custom character inside string containing variable depends on the group variable?

Here is the dummy input dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)
unit <- c(50, 50, 40, 40, 30, 30, 20, 20, 10, 10)

id <- c("A100", "A101", "A102", "A103", "A100", "A101", "A102", "A103", "A101", "A100")
variation <- c("aaa1", "aaa1", "bbb1", "aaa2", "b1","a3", "a1", "b1", "a1", "b1" )
result <- c("Way1", "Way1", "Way2", "Way2", "Way3","Way1", "Way2", "Way3", "Way4", "Way1" )

data <- data.frame(id, variation, result, unit)
head(data)

#      id variation result unit
# 1  A100      aaa1   Way1   50
# 2  A101      aaa1   Way1   50
# 3  A102      bbb1   Way2   40
# 4  A103      aaa2   Way2   40
# 5  A100        b1   Way3   30
# 6  A101        a3   Way1   30
# 7  A102        a1   Way2   20
# 8  A103        b1   Way3   20
# 9  A101        a1   Way4   10
# 10 A100        b1   Way1   10
```

And is it possible to add custom string character in the "variation" columns depends on the "unit" column?

Here is the expected output::

```
#         id variation result unit
# 1  A100      A1.aaa1   Way1   50
# 2  A101      A1.aaa1   Way1   50
# 3  A102      A2.bbb1   Way2   40
# 4  A103      A2.aaa2   Way2   40
# 5  A100        A3.b1   Way3   30
# 6  A101        A3.a3   Way1   30
# 7  A102        A4.a1   Way2   20
# 8  A103        A4.b1   Way3   20
# 9  A101        A5.a1   Way4   10
# 10 A100        A5.b1   Way1   10
```

As you can see if "unit" variable is the same then same custom strings were added to that "variation" variable.

dplyr and base R functions preferred.

Comment: hi choij! 1. is the first group always A1? 2. why is unit == 10 not A5?

Comment: hi, i also would like to know if its possible to define custom characters. For example from A1 to A4, B1 to B4 etc..

Comment: what do you mean by custom characters?

Comment: OP dplyr is a part of tidyverse, loading it again is redundant, it's already loaded by tidyverse

Comment: I meant that is it possible to define custom groups, for example: A1 to A4 is consider as a 1 group, then B1 to B4 is consider as a another group etc instead of A1, A2 ---- A11 etc..

Comment: yeah, that's definitely possible. Once again I ask, why is unit == 10 not A5?

Comment: it can be definetily possible that  unit == 10 is A5. There is no specific reason.

Comment: if that's the case, how are we supposed to answer this question? I need to come up with a set of rules and logic for creating the groups....

Comment: I edited the question, now unit == 10 is A5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data |> mutate(variation = paste0("A", cumsum(unit != lag(unit, default = first(unit))) + 1,".", variation))
```

Output:

```
     id variation result unit
1  A100   A1.aaa1   Way1   50
2  A101   A1.aaa1   Way1   50
3  A102   A2.bbb1   Way2   40
4  A103   A2.aaa2   Way2   40
5  A100     A3.b1   Way3   30
6  A101     A3.a3   Way1   30
7  A102     A4.a1   Way2   20
8  A103     A4.b1   Way3   20
9  A101     A5.a1   Way4   10
10 A100     A5.b1   Way1   10
```

Note: it's probably better to just have a group column, instead of creating this. It doesn't appear that the letter at the beginning is adding anything.